# ResultSet to Array

Tags: java, android, jdbc

I have a Result set returned using a query:

```
String query = "select Bookname, SubjectName from books join Subjects on Subjects.SubjectID = Books.subjectID where classID = '1a'";
ResultSet temp = null;
try
{
   Statement st = conn.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

   temp = rs;
}
```

I was just wondering is it possible to turn the Resultset into two seperate arrays: eg BookName[] and BookSubject[] so I can show them in a list view later on? Relatively new to resultset and this concept in android

Comment: the ResultSet object has methods to read the columns. You can use them to read the values and load your arrays. Instead of creating two separate arrays you should probably create a class that maps your books, if you do not have one already. There are also frameworks like OrmLite that are used to do this mapping properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to easily iterate through the results on the result set, populating each array with the results as you interate.

Something like this:

```
...
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> subjects = new ArrayList<String>();

while (rs.next()) { 
    names.add(rs.getString(1));
    subjects.add(rs.getString(2));
}

// finally turn the array lists into arrays - if really needed
String[] nameArr = new String[names.size()];
nameArr = names.toArray(nameArr);

String[] subjectArr = new String[subjects.size()];
subjectArr = subjects.toArray(subjectArr);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you know tha maximum resultset size, is faster create an array of that size and after use System.arrayCopy instead of create an Arraylist?

Comment: I'm not sure I got the idea... what array would be copied by System.arrayCopy? I don't think it can read directly from a ResultSet

Comment: Why don't you just `String[] nameArr = names.toArray(nameArr);`?

Comment: because when the right hand side executes the nameArr variable would not exist yet